# what is this.e in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am learning to make library like jquery and trying to understand a piece of code where this.e is giving me hard time, where this 'e' come from and they are assigning object to it but when they return this they return just this not this.e .

```
function _(a) {
  var b = {
    key: "some val"
  };
  if (a) {
    if (window === this) {
      return new _(a)
    }
    this.e = document.getElementById(a);
    return this
  } else {
    return b
  }
}
_.prototype = {
    hide: function() {
      this.e.style.display = "none";
      return this
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="_('abc')">click</button>
<div id="abc" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: pink;">   </div>
```

Comment: `this.e` comes from `this.e = document.getElementById(a);`. If that doesn't answer your question I think you need to give a bit more details about what part is confusing you, EG. why are you confused about `this.e = X` but not confused about `_.prototype = Y`?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object

Comment: because prototype is a there, that is builtin thing

Comment: You should research dynamic programming language. You can assign anything to an object at run time.

Comment: `.e` is an object property named `e`. `this.foo = 'bar';` --- that's how you set the `'bar'` string to the `foo` property of the `this` object.

Comment: okeyyy so "this" is an object a built in object and we are adding a property to that object okey gr8 understood

Comment: @user6920839 Just a heads up, the accepted answer *is wrong*.

Answer (score -3):

It's just a convention to use e as function parameter name when the parameter is event. as in your example here the event is onclick

Comment: In OP's example, `e` appears to be an element, not an event

Comment: This makes no sense at all! `e` is never used as a function parameter, and `e` is not an event!